# how to access "application data" folder in windows 10 phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I need access to raw files (hidden and system) stored on my phone, how to do it ? Do I need to 'root' it, download a special file explorer ?

I cannot find it on google because all I get are answers for win 10 destkop.

Comment: interop/deviceUnlock your phone (http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/vcreg-lumia-reg-editor-interop-unlock-t3451723) and use this app to get the userdata of your app: http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-app-data-manage-tool-t3443623

Comment: Thank you, will try in the morning. I assume it will also work for windows 10 mobile?

Comment: yes, those are explicate for Win10 mobile. in Build 14393 you can also try device portal: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#app-file-explorer